# Django Models referencing

Tags: django, django-models

i am tring to create a django models with following fields

```
Ruleinfo(Character field)
Ispname(Character field)
Priority (Character field)
From (Character field)
To(Character field)
```

Mine problem is ,for each Ispname their can be many(more then one ) Ruleinfo and for each Ruleinfo their can be many(more then one ) number of Priority.I am writing a model like

```
class Rule(models.Model):
    Ruleinfo = models.CharField(max_length=5,null=False)
    Ispname  = models.CharField(max_length=5,null=False)
    priority = models.ForeignKey('Priority')
    From  =    models.IntegerField(null=True)
    To = models.IntegerField(null=True)


class Priority(models.Model):  
    priority =  models.IntegerField(null = True)
    ispname = models.ForeignKey('Rule')
    rule = models.ForeignKey('Rule')
```

but this model is not validating any idea where i am going wronge ?

Comment: just ping me if any clarification required .

Comment: @DrTyrsa Unable to design the model because i have very less knowledge  of database  design (any references or link ?)

Comment: Try at least something. Then post the result here and we'll think how to make it better.

Answer (score 0):

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#charfield):

> `CharField` has one extra required argument:
>
> **`CharField.max_length`**

Comment: Are you going to continue making us what the rest of it is then?

Comment: thanx actually i was not adding related_name now i got it .